# Create Test data with master detail relationship

Tags: apex, unit-test, code-coverage, master-detail

I am trying to create a test data for coverage. The field is a formula field and it has a master-detail relationship with another object, then I create a recode in the object. but how can I reference the field in the detail object? I am getting an error:

> Field is not writeable

How Can I do that?
The `PLS_Code__c` is a formula field and formulae are: `Positioner_Limit_Switch__r.Code__c`

```
    VWC_Positioner_LimitSwitch__c  PLSObj = new VWC_Positioner_LimitSwitch__c();

    PLSObj.Code__c = '2HPB';

    PLSObj.Description__c   = 'This is test data.';

    insert PLSObj;        

    VWC_PLS_Combination__c pls_Combination = new VWC_PLS_Combination__c();        

    pls_Combination.Price__c = 123;        

    pls_Combination.Positioner_Limit_Switch__r.Code__c = PLSObj.id;        
    insert pls_Combination;       
    instance.selectedPositioner = '2HPB';`
```

Comment: once you insert pls_Combination, you must be able to access the formula value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your formula field is referencing the `Code__c` field of the `VWC_Positioner_LimitSwitch__c` object linked to your `VWC_PLS_Combination__c` object using its `Positioner_Limit_Switch__c` field.

By definition, a formula field is calculated. Once your `VWC_Positioner_LimitSwitch__c` object will be linked to your `VWC_PLS_Combination__c` object, the field will be calculated.

So you only have to replace your line:

```
pls_Combination.Positioner_Limit_Switch__r.Code__c = PLSObj.id;
```

By:

```
pls_Combination.Positioner_Limit_Switch__c = PLSObj.id;
```

Comment: You saved my Life, I was stuck there for many hours!

Comment: Glad I could help @samiullah !

Answer (score 0):

Please check this new test data factory library Apex Test Kit:
https://github.com/ApexTestKit/ApexTestKit

Your scenario can be transformed like this, and relationship is automatically assigned for you:

```
ATKWizard.I().wantMany('VWC_Positioner_LimitSwitch__c')
    .fields(new Map<String, Object> {
        'Code__c' => '2HPB'
        'Description__c' => '{!lorem.sentence}' // generate dummy text, can be omitted
    })
    .total(1)
    .hasMany('VWC_PLS_Combination__c')
        .fields(new Map<String, Object> {
            'Price__c' => 123
        })
        .total(1)
    .generate();
```

With ApexTestKit 1.0, it focuses on data generation only. If it is getting popular and wanted by the community, 2.0 will provide BDD functions.